# besides default endpoint create custom endpoints

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I am following this tutorial

http://learncooltech.com/yii2-angular-how-to-create-single-page-application-in-minutes/

I got this tutorial to work and now I can see GET /books: list all books page by page;

However, now I want to create some endpoints and in my controller I added a method test but I get a 404. here is my controller

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class BookController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Book';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return 
        \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
            'corsFilter' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            ],
        ]);
    }


    public function actionTest(){
        return json_encode(array("name"=>"John Doe"));
    }

}
```

I have this as my urlRule

```
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['book']],
            ],
        ],
```

and I am doing

```
http://localhost/events/test
```

to get to the endpoint

and I get this

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="cWdHTlZnWE8uNn5jEDQVHwZXJDcUIykKADUjAgM/Ei4dXn4mOAwNCg==">
        <title>Not Found (#404)</title>
        <link href="/assets/a7503887/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working by changing rule to this

```
 'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' =>
                    ['book'],
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                          'GET test' => 'test',
                ],
                ],
```